# How to pass a variable to html in a mail script?

Tags: python

My code like this:

```
success_msg='''\
<html>
    Hi. {{ name }}
    ...
'''
def sendmail(sender,receiver,title,content,username):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendmail(XXX,XXX,XXX,success_msg,usernameXX)
```

How to pass the "username" to "name" in html?
How to write the code in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string templates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> msg = Template("Hi $name")
>>> msg.substitute(name='World')
'Hi World'
```

HTML Example:

```
>>> header = '<html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body>'
>>> body = '<p>Hello <strong>$name</strong></p>'
>>> footer = '</body></html>'
>>> html = Template(header+body+footer)
>>> html.substitute(name='World')
'<html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body><p>Hello <strong>World</strong></
p></body></html>'
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter as long as its a string.